# showing html_instructions with ajax jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

From this link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Jalan+Kaliurang&destination=Jalan+Malioboro, loaded via an ajax request, how can I extract and display only the ***html instructions***

Here the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Coba Ajax JQuery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#driver').click(function(event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Jalan+Kaliurang&destination=Jalan+Malioboro",
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(data) {
                            var string_data = JSON.stringify(data);
                            $('#stage').html(string_data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                        alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
        <div id="stage">STAGE</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Where does that string of text live - on the page? So you're asking how to grab some text from within the DOM?

Comment: @Utkanos looks like the said link is in fact a JSON response that have an *html_instructions* property

Comment: @b.enoit.be also there seem to be multiple `html_instructions` properties in the JSON object

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen to that only OP can reply, logic would want all of them to be displayed

Comment: Looks like you want to load in a JSON. You can use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to load in your data directly into an object and access it via `data.html_instructions` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.parse and not JSON.stringify. The response you are getting from AJAX call is already a JSON. You need to parse it.

var data_obj=JSON.parse(data);

This data_obj will be a bit complicated as it will create arrays of elements. So in order to access the html_instructions you need to run loops with correct index of array. If you can tell me the exact html_instructions you want to use I can give you the code to access it.

In case you want to figure it out on your own. Just console.log(data_obj) and see the structure and write the loop accordingly.